# Heroku won't run their sample sinatra app, error is bundler: failed to load command: rackup

Tags: heroku, sinatra

How does one get a "hello world" sinatra app to execute on Heroku? Heroku's own sample app fails:

For a brand new heroku app, following Heroku's 3-file "hello world" Sinatra deployment instructions at:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack
the build fails with `bundler: failed to load command: rackup`

I've tried it with both the default stack (heroku-20) and thinking that might be the issue tried it on the heroku-18 stack. Same error.

```
#config.ru
require './hello'
run Sinatra::Application
```

and

```
#hello.rb
require 'sinatra'
get '/' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

and

```
#Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'
```

Gives:

```
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p ${PORT:-5000}`
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: rackup (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/rackup)
app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/handler.rb:45:in `pick': Couldn't find handler for: puma, thin, falcon, webrick. (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite what the Heroku docs say, the Gemfile *also* needs a web server.

Adding `gem 'puma'` to the Gemfile did the trick.